# Checking if no rows exist for a primary key SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have four (relevent) tables

```
CAKETABLE
CAKE      ICING

RESERVEDSPRINKLES
CAKE      SPRINKLE

SPRINKLETABLE
SPRINKLE  CONSUMED

ICINGTABLE
ICING     CONSUMED
```

Each cake has exactly 3 sprinkles and 1 icing.

I want to query the database and get all the cakes that have 1 icing and 3 sprinkles where neither icing nor any of the sprinkles have CONSUMED = '1'.

So let's psuedo insert data:
    INSERT INTO ICINGTABLE (vanilla, 0), (chocolate, 0);

```
INSERT INTO SPRINKLETABLE (red, 0), (blue, 0), (green, 0), (orange, 0), (purple, 0),(pink, 0);

INSERT INTO CAKETABLE (cake1, vanilla), (cake2, chocolate);

INSERT INTO RESERVEDSPRINKLES (cake1, red), (cake1, blue), (cake1, green), (cake2, orange), (cake2, purple), (cake2, pink);
```

So now I have cake1 with vanilla icing and red,blue,green sprinkles and cake2 with chocolate icing and orange, purple, and pink sprinkles.

When I run the query, I want it to return

```
CAKES
cake1
cake2
```

ONLY IF there are no consumed parts in the cake, so even if ONE sprinkle is marked consumed I want to omit that whole cake from the query.
The following query does exactly that for icing.

```
SELECT CAKE
FROM CAKETABLE as c
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ICINGTABLE WHERE CONSUMED = '0') as i
ON c.ICING = i.ICING;
```

But for the sprinkles, I am having trouble. If I use the same technique as above, my query will return:

```
CAKE
cake1
cake1
cake1
cake2
cake2
cake2
```

I can eliminate that with DISTINCT, but it still isn't correct because if any sprinkle has consumed = '0' it shows that cake in the list when I want the opposite functionality (cake only shown if ALL sprinkles have consumed = '0')

If anyone has a better title name for this, it'd be appreciated. I can't think of anything descriptive and short.

Comment: ICINGTABLE (table i) does not have CAKE? You have N c.CAKE = i.CAKE;, but in the schema you provided CAKE is not a column in the ICINGTABLE

Comment: The cake is a lie.  "Maybe Black Mesa? HAHA! That was a joke." -- GLaDOS

Comment: @james31rock You're right, my mistake. It should be joining on ICING as both CAKETABLE AND ICINGTABLE have icing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to demand that no icing or sprinkle is consumed:

```
select  cake
from    caketable c
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    icingtable i
        where   i.cake = c.cake
                and i.consumed = '1'
        )
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    sprinkletable s
        where   s.cake = c.cake
                and s.consumed = '1'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a cake will always have exactly three sprinkles, you can `GROUP BY` cake and use `HAVING` to filter any cakes that don't have 3 unconsumed sprinkles:

```
SELECT CAKE
FROM CAKETABLE as C
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM ICINGTABLE WHERE CONSUMED = '0'
) as I ON C.CAKE = I.CAKE
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CAKE FROM SPRINKLETABLE 
    WHERE CONSUMED = '0'
    GROUP BY CAKE
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) as S ON C.CAKE = S.CAKE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want:

```
select ct.cake
from caketable ct join
     reservedsprinkle rs
     on ct.cake = rs.cake join
     sprinkletable st
     on rs.sprinkle = st.sprinkle join
     icingtable it
     on ct.cake = it.cake
where it.consumed = 0
group by ct.cake
having count(distinct rs.sprinkle) = 3 and
       sum(case when st.consumed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This is grouping by cake and then putting most of the conditions in the HAVING clause.  It looks like a cake can have only one icing, by database design.  I am assuming that CAKE is unique in the CAKE table.